# RESPONSIVE TABLE - How To Make <td> In The Table Drop Down Instead Of Sideways

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

I want to create a responsive table. When I open the page using the mobile screen, I want `<td>` in the table to automatically go down. So, there should be two columns sideways, but when opening using a mobile display, the two columns will go down.

This is the HTML code that I made:

```css
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="kotak_artikel">
  <table id="isikotak_artikel">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x160/000/fff" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2 class="judulartikel">Title 1</h2>
        <p class="penjelasan_judulartikel">Content 1</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x160/000/fff" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2 class="judulartikel">Title 2</h2>
        <p class="penjelasan_judulartikel">Content 2</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x160/000/fff" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2 class="judulartikel">Title 3</h2>
        <p class="penjelasan_judulartikel">Content 3</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x160/000/fff" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2 class="judulartikel">Title 4</h2>
        <p class="penjelasan_judulartikel">Content 4</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x160/000/fff" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2 class="judulartikel">Title 5</h2>
        <p class="penjelasan_judulartikel">Content 5</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image: this table what I want]

Comment: That will need media queries, have you tried using those?

Answer (score 1):

Simply apply css `display: block;` to `<td>` will be done.

```css
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

table#isikotak_artikel tr td {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="kotak_artikel">
  <table id="isikotak_artikel">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x160/000/fff" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2 class="judulartikel">Title 1</h2>
        <p class="penjelasan_judulartikel">Content 1</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x160/000/fff" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2 class="judulartikel">Title 2</h2>
        <p class="penjelasan_judulartikel">Content 2</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x160/000/fff" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2 class="judulartikel">Title 3</h2>
        <p class="penjelasan_judulartikel">Content 3</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x160/000/fff" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2 class="judulartikel">Title 4</h2>
        <p class="penjelasan_judulartikel">Content 4</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x160/000/fff" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2 class="judulartikel">Title 5</h2>
        <p class="penjelasan_judulartikel">Content 5</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```